# Solitaire implementation in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a simple [8off solitaire game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Off) in haskell and I am not quite sure how to define my board, and how to make a function to return a random starting board. How can I modify myBoard and my data structure? Until now, I have these:

```
data Pip = A|TW0|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|TEN|J|Q|K  --pip value
       deriving (Eq,Show)
data Suit = S|H|D|C                                              --suit
       deriving (Eq,Show)
type Card = (Pip,Suit)                                           --card
type Deck = [(Card)]                                             --deck
type Foundations = [(Deck)]                                        foundations
type Columns = [(Deck)]                                          --columns
type Reserve = [(Deck)]                                          --reserve
type EOBoard = [(Deck)]

myBoard::Deck->EOBoard
myBoard pack = [shuffle pack]
```

which returns me, this:

```
[[(K,D),(TW0,H),(SEVEN,C),(SEVEN,S),(THREE,D),(NINE,S),(THREE,C),(FOUR,H),(THREE,S),(TW0,D),(TW0,C),(FOUR,S),(K,S),(TEN,D),(J,S),(EIGHT,H),(FOUR,D),(NINE,H),(SEVEN,H),(A,S),(SIX,S),(EIGHT,S),(FIVE,S),(FOUR,C),(K,H),(Q,D),(THREE,H),(TEN,H),(A,D),(EIGHT,C),(NINE,D),(Q,H),(J,D),(J,C),(TEN,C),(Q,S),(Q,C),(J,H),(NINE,C),(SIX,C),(FIVE,H),(SEVEN,D),(A,C),(TW0,S),(EIGHT,D),(FIVE,D),(TEN,S),(K,C),(A,H),(SIX,D),(FIVE,C),(SIX,H)]]
```

Comment: Note that `[(Deck)]` is just `[Deck]` and likewise for `[(Card)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're off to a good start! Perhaps you're ready to put some of these components together to form your board.

You might consider making a Board/Game ADT.

You might then like to have a default function, which sets up the default state of your Board.

- A `defaultFoundation` which returns a `Foundation` containing four empty `Deck`s
- A `defaultColumns` which takes a `Deck` and splits it, returning a `Columns` containing 8 `Deck`s with 6 cards each (maybe you want to only pass in the first 48 cards from the Deck only).
- A `defaultReserves` which returns a `Reserve` with 8 `Deck`s, 4 with cards and 4 empty (maybe here is where you want to pass in those remaining 4 cards from the `Deck`)

You're doing fine so far, take it one step at a time. :)

Comment: Thanks so much @Mario. I will try that and see the result

Comment: How can I control the number of cards I am passing into Columns for example. How can I split those columns into 8 equal of 6 each?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for Lists, in particular Sublists. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:18

Comment: eODeal::EOBoard
eODeal = EOBoard { foundations = defaultFoundations,
                   columns=defaultColumns pack48, --first 48 cards 
                   reserve=defaultReserve (shuffle pack) }
If I have this implementation, how can I access foundations field of that EOBoard for example? To make some moves between the cards?

Comment: If you have an `EOBoard`, the ADT will define "getters" with the names of each attribute. I.e `foundations :: EOBoard -> Deck`. So if you had some `eoboard`, then `foundations(eoboard)` would give you the foundations value.

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from reading up about ADTs, would recommend this whole guide, but relevant is Chapter 8: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types